# Drawing Four Leaf Rose in Java

Tags: java, polar-coordinates

Really having trouble trying to draw a four leaf rose: This is the exercise:

Draw a picture of the “four­leaved rose” whose equation in polar coordinates is 
r =cos(2θ) . Let  θ go from 0 to 2*pi in 100 steps. Each time, compute r and then com­pute the (x, y) coordinates from the polar coordinates by using the formula
x = r ⋅ cos( θ) , y = r ⋅  sin(θ )

My Code:

```
public Rose(double awidth, double aheight)
{
    width = awidth;
    height = aheight;
    theta = 0;
}


 public void drawRose(Graphics2D g2)
{
      Ellipse2D.Double test ; 
  double r = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
   {
          r = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(2*theta)    );
      x = r *(    Math.cos(  Math.toRadians(theta) ) * width )  + 300;
          y = r * (  Math.sin(  Math.toRadians(theta) )   * height ) + 300 ;
     test = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, width, height);  
     theta += 3.6;
     g2.draw(test);
   }        
}
```

}

Any help will be greatly appreciately.

Comment: And what, exactly, is wrong with your implementation?

Comment: Myself, I'd not create Ellipse2D objects, but rather create a `List<Point>` using the  formulas, and then draw lines between the points in the list.

Comment: I have not learned about List<Point> yet.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, it won't draw the four leaf rose

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest mistake is here:

```
test = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
```

You're creating 100 Ellipses with the points that are on the rose, but that with heights and widths of the desired rose. You really don't want 100 ellipses, but rather you want to connect lines between the x and y points you've created, that is connect the current x, y with the previous ones created (as long as there is a previous x and y).

One way is via these suggestions, but there are other ways to do this:

- Use a [Path2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html) object, the concrete implementation would be a Path2D.Double, to hold your data points. Create this before creating data points.
- Use a for loop that goes from 0 to 100, and do this in the class's constructor
- set your double theta in the loop
- set your double `r` variable in the loop
- Calculate your x and y double points
- Scale your x and y points by multiplying them with a scale factor so that the drawing has some size. I used 150.0
- Translate your x and y values by adding a translation constant. I used 200 and it worked nicely in a 400 x 400 JPanel. Else the center of the rose will be at 0, 0 and only a fourth of it will be visible.
- In the first iteration of the for loop call the Path2D's `moveTo(...)` method to add a starting point
- In all other iterations call the `lineTo(...)` method. This will draw a line between neighboring points.
- After the for loop, close the path by calling `closePath()` on it.
- Draw the path in your JPanel's paintComponent method by casting your Graphics parameter into a Graphics2D object (actually you don't need this since your draw method gets a Grahpics2D object), and calling `draw(path)` with the Graphics2D object, passing in your Path2D object.

---

For example, this is created:

[image]
with this code:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class RosePanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final int MAX = 100;
   private static final double SCALE = 150.0;
   private static final double DELTA_X = 200;
   private static final double DELTA_Y = DELTA_X;
   private static final Color ROSE_COLOR = Color.red;
   private static final Stroke ROSE_STROKE = new BasicStroke(8f);
   private Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();

   public RosePanel() {

      for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
         double theta = i * 2 * Math.PI / MAX;
         double r = Math.cos(2 * theta);
         double dX = SCALE * r * Math.cos(theta) + DELTA_X;
         double dY = SCALE * r * Math.sin(theta) + DELTA_Y;
         if (i == 0) {
            path.moveTo(dX, dY);
         } else {
            path.lineTo(dX, dY);
         }
      }
      path.closePath();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setColor(ROSE_COLOR);
      g2.setStroke(ROSE_STROKE);
      g2.draw(path);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      RosePanel mainPanel = new RosePanel();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("RosePanel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Note that the key difference between my code and yours, other than the translations and the scaling is that I'm connecting the line between points created.

Comment: Your suggestion looks good and all. However, I am still a greenhorn in Java. The things I know are the basics like loops, how to make classes... I justed picked a book and from it I am learning Java and trying to solve all the problems at the end of each chapter

Comment: @UstazMohammed: see edit to answer. Your biggest mistake is that you're trying to create 100 ellipses when you don't need nor want ellipses. You want to connect points.

Comment: I understand but the book I am using makes no mention of the class Path2D. Heck, I can't find it in my Java libraries. Without the Path class, is there another way. Should I use lines instead of ellipse? Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: I don't have Path2D class in my Java Library. Is there another way just using lines or ellipses??

Comment: @UstazMohammed: again, don't use ellipses but instead use lines. In your loop, draw a line from the previous point (if it exists) to the current point.

Comment: I will try your suggestion

Comment: Thanks!! It works some minor issues I will resolve on my own. Thanks again

Comment: @UstazMohammed: good show, and you did it on your own -- even better!